# Updating only one source in sources.list

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, updates

I have a program I would like to install. I was given an entry similar to the following:

```
deb http://example.org/example.org xenial main
```

and told to insert it in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, or to include it in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder, and after having done that, to use the command:

```
apt-get update
```

To my understanding, this updates all the different sources listed in both the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as well ass the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder.

**Question**

Is there a way for me only to update only the program I want to install, and not all the other sources listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the method using `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` yes:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="sources.list"
```

where `sources.list` is the one you created.

Be careful: If your repo contains older or newer versions of software than is installed from another repo that is not in the update you can run into trouble.